# iPhone battery life continually worsening

Tags: iphone, battery

I purchased my iPhone 4S on November 8th, 2013, now the iPhone first started having problems in summer, maybe in July.

The phone first died at 15%, eventually the problem got even worse. The phone then frequently died at 50%. Now don't stop reading yet. The phone then died at 60, then 70, then 80, then 90. When I plug the phone in the outlet the phone will zip all the way back up to 100% in 5 mins, then the phone will go down to 92% and die. Then i charge again, take the phone out and it goes down too 82% and dies. Can someone please give me some healthy, useful, advice so I can get my phone up and running perfectly again?

Answer (score 1):

The symptoms you report are common of lithium power cells that are failing.

Why not have it looked at by Apple as they have online battery diagnosis available from web support and if you bought it from an Apple Reseller or Apple Directly, the warranty should cover the problem if the battery isn't performing correctly.